# JAVACC tokens definition

Tags: java, javacc

I am working on a project using `javacc`, I have a problem and need some help, 
I have something like this in a file :

```
STRING COPYRIGHT (C) 2003, 2004 SYNOPSYS, INC.;
```

I have a token defined for the word `STRING` and I want to define another token (`NAME`) to get all the words `COPYRIGHT (C) 2003, 2004 SYNOPSYS, INC.`

The problem is that I have a token `INTEGER` and when it reach the word 2003 it says (`There was an error during the parse. Encountered INTEGER` :  2003 ...)

So how can I do to get the words between `"STRING"`  and `";"`

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to write a Lexer ?

Comment: what jj file are you using?

Comment: Yes i am writing a lexer !!
i am writing a .jj file

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that you want `<NAME>` to match all characters after "STRING" and before the ";" and also the semicolon itself

You can do this using lexical states.  You can read about them in the [FAQ](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/),  [the description of the grammar file](https://javacc.java.net/doc/docindex.html), and the [token manager minitutorial](https://javacc.java.net/doc/docindex.html).

In short the token manager productions look like this

```
TOKEN: { <STRING: "STRING" > : AFTERSTRING } // When "STRING" is encountered, switch to state AFTERSTRING
<AFTERSTRING> TOKEN : { <NAME: (~[";"])* ";" > : DEFAULT} // After the ";", return to the DEFAULT state.
```

And the parser production can then look like this:

```
void string() : {} { <STRING> <NAME> }
```

If the semicolon is missing the lexer will throw a `TokenManagerError`.

---

EDIT: To get a better error message in case of a missing semicolon you could do the following.

```
TOKEN: { <STRING: "STRING" > : AFTERSTRING } // When "STRING" is encountered, switch to state AFTERSTRING
<AFTERSTRING> TOKEN : { <NAME: (~[";"])* ";" > : DEFAULT} // After the ";", return to the DEFAULT state.
<AFTERSTRING> TOKEN : { <MISSING_SEMI: ~[] > : DEFAULT }
```

And the parser production can then look like this:

```
void string() : {
    Token t ;
} {
    t = <STRING>
    (
        <NAME>
    |
        <MISSING_SEMI>
        {throw new ParserException( "STRING must be followed by a \";\". at line"
                                 +t.beginLine+ ", column " +t.beginColumn+ "." ) ; }
    )
}
```

Comment: Note that this will consume all characters to the next semicolon, including newlines and line feeds.